# Cómo agregar una imagen a un svg

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Quiero poder poner dos imagenes en un svg cada una en un extremo de la línea, en el enlace de abajo hay un enlace que lleva a una pregunta de stackoverflow donde se muestra cómo agregar una imagen a un svg... Pero la cuestión es que ese svg se ve diferente a este y en este no logro hacerlo.

```html
<svg pointer-events="none" class="leaflet-zoom-animated" width="802" height="286" style="transform: translate3d(-190px, 44px, 0px);" viewBox="-190 44 802 286"><g><path class="leaflet-interactive" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" d="M336 121L270 219L99 93L22 201L34 209" stroke-width="4" style="stroke: #1e90ffab;"></path></g></svg>
```

[Aquí hay un ejemplo de que sí se puede hacer, pero no sé cómo hacerlo con este svg y con dos imagenes en los extremos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897108/how-can-i-display-an-image-inside-svg-circle-in-html5)

La idea es que quede así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]